# Delete all nodes in a linked list (in c)

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

I'm solving exercise 17.7 on page 454 in the book C Programming: A Modern Approach (http://knking.com/books/c/). The question is below:

> The following loop is supposed to delete all nodes from a linked list and release the memory they occupy. Unfortunately, the loop is incorrect. Explain what's wrong with it and show how to fix the bug.
>
> ```
> for (p = first; p != NULL; p = p->next)
>     free(p);
> ```

My solution is this:

```
struct node *next_node;
p = first;

while (p != NULL) {
    next_node = p->next;
    free(p);
    p = next_node;
}
```

Is my answer correct?

Comment: Your approach is correct, but you should post a full function to show all definitions and what happens to `first` after the loop.

Comment: What you have is correct.  Once you free `p`, you should not attempt to access it.  In particular, you should treat `p->next` as undefined once `p` has been freed, since the storage it pointed to is no longer validly allocated and may have changed.  Capturing that value before passing `p` to `free` solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is fine, but if all you provide is a corrected version, your answer is incomplete: you should first explain why `p = p->next` has undefined behavior once `p` has been freed with `free(p)`.

You might also define `next_node` with a tighter scope, inside the loop:

```
p = first;
while (p != NULL) {
    struct node *next_node = p->next;
    free(p);
    p = next_node;
}
```

Here is an alternate correction as a single statement for consistency with the code fragment in the question.

```
for (p = first; p != NULL; ) {
    struct node *next_node = p->next;
    free(p);
    p = next_node;
}
```

Comment: I prefer leaving the declaration where it is, and instead moving `p = next_node` into the step portion of the `for` statement.  That seems clearest to me.

Comment: @TomKarzes: I agree it would be better style, but since we are fix a code fragment, it makes sense to keep it as a single statement.

Comment: @TomKarzes Do you mean that it would be clearer to keep for loop not changing it to while statement because what you are asked for in this question is to fix the code?

Comment: @chqrlie "you should first explain why p = p->next has undefined behavior once p has been freed with free(p)." - It's because the original version is to try to access deallocated memory block and it leads to undefined behaviour?

Comment: @Fary: the question is *Explain what's wrong with it and show how to fix the bug.* so you should first **explain** the problem, ie: `p = p->next` has undefined behavior once `p` has been freed with `free(p)` because the object pointed to by `p` is no longer valid to access, then provide a corrected version, either as a `while` loop or a `for` loop, which is a lesser matter of style.

Answer (score 2):

Why should there be **three** pointers in this exercise? Perhaps that is the *confusion* of dereferencing the pointer `p` AFTER the memory block it points to has been returned to the system.

```
while( first ) {
    struct node *del = first; // the node to 'free'
    first = first->next; // advance along the LL
    free( del ); // free that node
}
```

The scope of the variable passed to `free()` is limited. And, the value of `first` will be `NULL` at the end of the looping. Don't write more code than is necessary. And, be alert to the scope of variables; `p` and `first` are an unnecessary duplication that may lead to problems.

(Personal taste in rearranging the sequence of operations inside the block.)

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of all extra variables (and arguments about scope) by using recursion:

```
void freelist(struct node *p)
    {
    if (p)
        {
        freelist(p->next);
        free(p);
        }
    }
```